# How to Import custom python package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have made a small python package that is structured in the following way:

```sh
my_package/
    |_setup.py
    |___directory/
           |_directory.py
           |__init__.py
```

In the `setup.py`

```py
import setuptools

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(name='directory',
version='0.3',
description='Testing installation of Package',
url='#',
author='my name',
author_email='my_mail@gmail.com',
license='MIT',
packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
install_requires=requirements,
zip_safe=False)
```

The `__init__.py` is empty. To use my package I have to import it using below:
`from directory.directory import Directory` but I would like to import it as `from directory import Directory`. What do I have to do in order to be able to import it in that way?

After running `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` the following is in `SOURCES.txt`

```
README.md
setup.py
directory/__init__.py
directory/directory.py
directory.egg-info/PKG-INFO
directory.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
directory.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
directory.egg-info/not-zip-safe
directory.egg-info/requires.txt
directory.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your `__init__.py` the following line:

`from directory import Directory`

It will then directly import the function `Directory` defined into the file `directory.py` each time you load the module.

Comment: I've added `from directory import Directory` in the `__init__.py` file resulting in `ImportError: cannot import name 'Directory` being thrown from the init file.

Comment: The code should be placed inside `my_package/__init.py__` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `from .directory import Directory` to `__init__.py`.
Solution found [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html).